# Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined" (Vue)

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

i just learn about vuejs using state management like vuex.

I got this error

> Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

when i  populate my data from server like this :

```
authenticated:{
  created_at:"2019-12-13 16:04:47"
  email:"super@vetura.id"
  email_verified_at:"2019-12-13 16:04:47"
  employee:{
    accountNumber:null
    address:"JL.VETERAN UTARA LR.124 NO.1"
    baseSalary:"10000000.000000"
    birthDate:"1987-09-14"
    birthPlace:"Ujung Pandang"
    category_id:null
    classification_id:null
    code:"000001"
    created_at:"2019-12-13 16:04:47"
    dateJoin:"2012-01-04"
    dateResign:null
    department_id:null
    division_id:null
    gender:null
    group_id:null
    height:172
    id:1
    idCardNumber:null
    kecamatan:null
    kelurahan:null
  }
  employee_id:1
  id:1
  role:"0"
  updated_at:"2019-12-15 14:22:26"
}
```

Actually, the data response can display on template, when i try to populate `authenticated.employee.name` the console show me an error but data can display.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Anyone can  help me ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muTEI.png)

Sorry my english is bad. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you display your data try like this:

```
authenticated.employee && authenticated.employee.name
```

or

```
authenticated.employee ? authenticated.employee.name : ''
```

This is because in moment `authenticated.employee` is not defined.

With that error will disappear.

You can read [more here](https://hackernoon.com/accessing-nested-objects-in-javascript-f02f1bd6387f) about that.

Comment: Perfect bro. it work bro.. Thanks,  we must checking first, im not thinking that before, whether the data not fully load by vue??

Comment: You are welcome, please mark it as answer if it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that in the response from the server the employee is null. As in there was no employee id on the user or the employee with that id doesn't exist.

If the above is not the issue. Personally I like to use _.get() to handle a situation where there is the possibility of something in the 'path' being null and throwing this error.

```
let employeeName = _.get(response, 'employee.name');
```

What that does is handle checking if employee is not null before trying the name. employeeName would be null if employee is null. It means you don't have to chain a bunch of parent checks like this:

```
if (response.employee && response.employee.name) {
    let employeeName = response.employee.name;
}
```

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get

Comment: Ya it work bro.. Thanks,  we must checking first, im not thinking that before, whether the data not fully load by vue??